# I Node and Data Retrieval

Tags: linux, inode, data

Is there a way possible to open a data block without the file if we know the i node number that it's linked to ? Is it possible to open the content in data block without the file ?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92816/can-a-file-be-retrieved-by-its-inode

Comment: Have a look at `debugfs` (only for ext2/ext3/ext4, but other FS may not even have i-nodes ...)