# Bring back a deleted file without copying its content

Tags: linux, bash, c, file-descriptors

As long as there is an open file descriptor pointing to a file, I can bring it back with `cp` like this:

```
# Open for reading
exec 3< file
# Delete
rm file
# Bring it back
cp /proc/self/fd/3 file
```

This solution is okay with small files, but it's really slow with larger ones (like >5GiB). So I wonder, is there a way of bringing it back without copying the content? I mean, the data lies there untouched unless the descriptor is closed, so why shouldn't it be possible to link a filename to the memory area the data resides?

Please enlighten me on this. A hackish command line solution, a platform/filesystem dependent C API etc. everything is welcome; I just want to know **if this is possible** somehow somewhere, and **if not**, I want to know **why**.

Googling didn't help at all, all I could find is copy-of-copy articles about how to restore files with `lsof` and `cp`.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505820/90691

Comment: Yes @Andy that question led me to answers I was looking for, thank you