# Recover deleted but mounted loop file/filesystem

Tags: linux, data-recovery, lxc, loop-device

By mistake, I deleted an lxc image file. The container is still running and the file is therefore not yet actually deleted until I stop the container. I'd like to avoid stopping the container as it is quite sensitive.

I tried to find the deleted file with:
`for i in $(ls /proc/|grep '^[0-9]*$'); do ls -l /proc/$i/fd|grep delete; done`
But this doesn't find my loop device. Same with a simple `lsof | vm-`

If I run lsof on another image that is not delete, it doesn't show me any process using it: `lsof /var/lib/vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-0.raw`. Probably because it's open by the kernel, not a process.

As suggested in comment:

```
# losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                          DIO
/dev/loop1         0      0         1  0 /var/lib/vz/images/200/vm-200-disk-0.raw (deleted)   0
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  0 /var/lib/vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-0.raw             0
```

I tried:

```
debugfs /dev/mapper/pve-data
debugfs:  cd images/200
debugfs:  lsdel
 Inode  Owner  Mode    Size      Blocks   Time deleted
 0 deleted inodes found.
```

I guess that's because it's not deleted yet. It is a bit risky to just let it get deleted and hope that it appears here and doesn't get corrupted (it's >300Gb)

Inside the container, `mount` gives:

```
/var/lib/vz/images/200/vm-200-disk-0.raw (deleted) on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Any solution apart from dumping the entire filesystem and recreating the container entirely ? (Also, the host drive is almost full, I don't have enough space right now to create a second container next to it. I'm afraid that downsizing the storage would actually result it the actual deletion. :(

Comment: You have different names in `lsof` and the `mount` output.

Comment: `lsof` won't tell you about the backing files of the loop devices. `losetup -l` will tell you that. `cat /proc/self/mountinfo` inside the container will tell which loop device is mounted on `/`. But that's only half of the story -- if you have enough space on the disk and want just to recover the data, you can just `cat /dev/loopX /path/to/save`. If you want to resurrect a file on a live system/partition ... I have no idea how you could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[not a complete answer, but too long to put in a comment]

You can find the inode of a (possibly deleted) backing file of a loop device with the `LOOP_GET_STATUS` or `LOOP_GET_STATUS64` ioctls: it's the `.lo_inode` field of the `loop_info` and `loop_info64` structs.

As I wasn't able to find any command line utility exposing that info, here is perl one-liner that should do it:

```
perl -le 'ioctl STDIN, 0x4C05, $s = pack "a512" or die "ioctl: $!"; print unpack "x[Q]Q", $s' </dev/loop1
1179684
```

More info in the `loop(4)` manpage and in the `/usr/include/linux/loop.h` file.

But I don't know if there's any safe way to resurect a deleted file by its inode: I don't think that you can use `debugfs(8)` on a mounted live file system without corrupting it beyond repair, and there's [no way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494760/308316) to create a link to a deleted file.

The only safe way I can think of is to copy the whole loop device / partition while it's still live:

```
cp --sparse=always /dev/loop1 /path/where/to/save/it
```

Comment: I think that you're right and the debugfs approach is bound to do more harm than good. I appreciate the perl script . debugfs seems confused about that inode too, so it's better to leave it. The cp of /dev/loop1 is also an interesting idea. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the container is running, the file shouldn't be deleted from hard disk.

You can find the inode with `lsof` and possibly recover the file with `debugfs` as described in the answer from Andrew Gallagher to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process).

If you can mount an external disk to your server, you can try the accepted answer and copy the file there.

Comment: As stated in my question, lsof doesn't find the file.

Comment: What does `lsof | grep vm-200-disk-0.raw`show?. You have different names in the `lsof` and the `mount` output.

Comment: The deleted one is 200. The output of the 100 one is to show that even an existing mounted file doesn't show in lsof. `lsof | grep vm-` doesn't give any result.